# How to fill an area within a polygon in Python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, fill, convex-hull

Here is a code I tried:

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
points = np.random.rand(30, 2)   # 30 random points in 2-D
hull = ConvexHull(points)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
corners=[]
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    corners+=list(simplex)
plt.fill(points[corners, 0], points[corners, 1], 'k',alpha=0.3)
```

The only plot I can get is:
[Convex Hull of random set of points in matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jssn2.png)
As you can see it is filled partly.

But I'd like all the area within this polygon should be filled.

What are the ways of doing it?

I appreciate any your advice!

**Upd: An Answer!!!**

Actually I've just found an answer. It was on [the official site of SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull):

> We could also have directly used the vertices of the hull, which for 2-D are guaranteed to be in counterclockwise order

So to do what I want I just needed to use:

`plt.fill(points[hull.vertices,0], points[hull.vertices,1], 'k', alpha=0.3)`

instead of last 4 lines of my upper code.

May be this question/answer will help anyone else.

Comment: I guess you should sort the points by their polar angle and then plot them.

Comment: Please add this update as an answer, so others can see that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 17):

Actually I've just found an answer. It was on the official site of SciPy:

> We could also have directly used the vertices of the hull, which for 2-D are guaranteed to be in counterclockwise order
>   So to do what I want I just needed to use:

`plt.fill(points[hull.vertices,0], points[hull.vertices,1], 'k', alpha=0.3)`

instead of last 4 lines of my upper code.

May be this question/answer will help anyone else.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as "accepted", which can help other people reading and searching.